# How to transform Hierarchical data frame using spread/Pivot or Reshape

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse

I'm currently trying to reformat a library of documents in an descending hierarchical format. The docFrom column contains the higher level of document, and subDoc contains the lower level document, with the parent column representing the number of levels down the document is, with 1 being the document at the top. The data `Docs` is all strings and currently looks like this, the only difference is that subDoc contains all unique strings which the dummy data doesn't show, imagine them as actual names for the networks, shows and episodes.

```
    docFrom      subDoc           Parent  
    NA           Network 1        1 
    Network 1    TvShow 1         2
    Network 1    TvShow 2         2             
    Network 1    TvShow 3         2
    Network 1    TvShow 4         2 
    TvShow 1     Episode 1        3 
    TvShow 1     Episode 2        3 
    TvShow 2     Episode 1        3 
    TvShow 2     Episode 2        3 
    TvShow 3     Episode 1        3 
    TvShow 1     Episode 2        3
```

For visualization Purposes i want to transform this into

```
  1          2         3 
  Network 1  TvShow 1  Episode 1 
  Network 1  TvShow 1  Episode 2
  Network 1  TvShow 2  Episode 1 
  Network 1  TvShow 2  Episode 2 
  Network 1  TvShow 3  Episode 1 
  Network 1  TvShow 3  Episode 2
```

using `df <- reshape(Docs,idvar = "docFrom", timevar = "Parent", direction = "wide")` did not work, and neither did

`df <- spread(Docs, Parent, subDoc)`

I tried to find solutions but couldn't find any data that mirrored this situation. Is there any function that could be used to reshape a data frame like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We'll solve the problem with a combination of base R and the `sqldf()` package. We can use the `Parent` column to split the data into 3 data frames, and join the two resulting data frames where `Parent` is either 2 or 3 by TV show name.

```
textFile <- "docFrom  |subDoc   |Parent  
NA       |Network 1|1 
Network 1|TvShow 1 |2
Network 1|TvShow 2 |2             
Network 1|TvShow 3 |2
Network 1|TvShow 4 |2 
TvShow 1 |Episode 1|3 
TvShow 1 |Episode 2|3 
TvShow 2 |Episode 1|3 
TvShow 2 |Episode 2|3 
TvShow 3 |Episode 1|3 
TvShow 1 |Episode 2|3"

data <- read.csv(text = textFile,sep="|",stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
splitVar <- as.factor(data$Parent)
groupedData <- split(data,splitVar)

# second frame in list contains networks & shows
shows <- groupedData[[2]][-3]
colnames(shows) <- c("Network","Show")

# third frame in list contains shows and episodes
episodes <- groupedData[[3]][-3]
colnames(episodes) <- c("Show","Episode")

# use sqldf to join shows with episodes, since the shows data frame
# also includes the network names
library(sqldf)
sqlstmt <- "select s.Network, e.Show, e.Episode from shows s, episodes e where s.Show = e.Show"
result <- sqldf(sqlstmt)
result
```

...and the output:

```
> result
    Network      Show   Episode
1 Network 1 TvShow 1  Episode 1
2 Network 1 TvShow 1  Episode 2
3 Network 1 TvShow 1  Episode 2
4 Network 1 TvShow 2  Episode 1
5 Network 1 TvShow 2  Episode 2
6 Network 1 TvShow 3  Episode 1
>
```

### dplyr version

We can use `dplyr::inner_join()` to accomplish the same data frame join we made with `sqldf()`. Once we've split the incoming data into the separate data frames by value of `Parent`, extracted from the list to create `shows` and `episodes` data frames and renamed the columns, we join the two data frames as follows.

```
# dplyr version
library(dplyr)
shows %>% inner_join(episodes, by = "Show")
```

...and the output:

```
> shows %>% inner_join(episodes, by = "Show")
    Network      Show   Episode
1 Network 1 TvShow 1  Episode 1
2 Network 1 TvShow 1  Episode 2
3 Network 1 TvShow 1  Episode 2
4 Network 1 TvShow 2  Episode 1
5 Network 1 TvShow 2  Episode 2
6 Network 1 TvShow 3  Episode 1
>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess the best advice here is to firs split `Docs` into 2 distinct sets, `TVShows` and `Episodes`, e.g. `TvShows = filter(Docs, stringr::str_detect("TvShow"))`

Remove Parent column, adjust column names and then `full_join` them.